# How can I do a matrix-matrix product between a Linear Operator (Scipy) and a sparse matrix (CSC matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I'm using a mathematical object implemented in Python (H² matrices) which is an approximation of dense matrices (from h2tools library). This package only implemented a matrix-vector product, so I can create a linear operator that describes it.

I need to do a matrix product between a Linear Operator (from scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator) and a sparse matrix (CSC format). The result of this product needs to be in a sparse format.

Is there a way to do that with Scipy or any other library ?

I've tried on a simple example.

I created a sparse CSC matrix, and un linear operator from a matrix :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix
from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator

# Define a CSC matrix A
A = csc_matrix([[1, 0], [0, 1]])

# Creating Linear operator from another matrix
B = np.array([[10, 0], [0, 10]] )
lin_op_B = LinearOperator(B.shape, matvec=B.dot)
```

Then I want to perform matrix product :

```
# Perform the matrix-matrix multiplication
result = A @ lin_op_B
print(result.todense())
```

This sould print the B matrix :

[[10 0]

[0 10]]

In CSC format.

Comment: so what does  happen when you try that?

Comment: Skipping the linear operator stuff, what you are doing is `B.dot(A)`.  But this only works if `A` itself is dense.  It does not work with a sparse `A`.  `B.dot(A.todense())`.  The sparse matrix has to control the `dot`   Or you could first make `B` sparse.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, applying the dot to the sparse matrix tries to do a purely dense dot.  The sparse docs try to stress this.

```
In [3]: B.dot(A)
Out[3]: 
array([[<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
            with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>,
        <2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
            with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>],
       [<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
            with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>,
        <2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
            with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>]],
      dtype=object)
```

The proper dot:

```
In [4]: B.dot(A.todense())
Out[4]: 
matrix([[10,  0],
        [ 0, 10]])
```

Or making B sparse

```
In [5]: csc_matrix(B).dot(A)
Out[5]: 
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.intc'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>

In [6]: csc_matrix(B).dot(A).todense()
Out[6]: 
matrix([[10,  0],
        [ 0, 10]], dtype=int32)
```

The matmul operator also works, but the result is dense

```
In [10]: B@A
Out[10]: 
array([[10,  0],
       [ 0, 10]], dtype=int32)
```

another dense result:

```
In [12]: A.T.dot(B.T)
Out[12]: 
array([[10,  0],
       [ 0, 10]], dtype=int32)
```

You'll get a sparse result only if `B` itself is sparse.  That is, dot/matmul of sparse with sparse produces sparse.  Otherwise spare with dense produces dense.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot build any dense matrix, it will cost too much in the future when I'll use larger matrices. Maybe there is a way to transform a linear operator into a sparse matrix ?